# Find the $P{X < Y}$ from this joint density function $f(x, y) = 6x^2y$

Tags: probability

I have a joint density function given as:

$$f(x, y) = 6x^2y \\
0\le x\le 1 \\
0\le y\le 1$$

Now I am asked to find the $P\{X < Y\}$, as well as the $P\{X < 2Y\}$

In order to solve this, I did the following integrals:

\begin{align}
P\{X < Y\} &= \int_0^1\int_0^Y6x^2y\,dx\,dy \\
&= 6\int_0^1y\,dy\int_0^Yx^2\,dx \\
&= 3\int_0^Yx^2\,dx \\
&= y^3
\end{align}

That seems correct to me, as plugging in a value of $1$ for $y$ results in a probability of $1$, which is intuitively correct.

**And for $P\{X < 2Y\}$:**

\begin{align}
P\{X < 2Y\} &= \int_0^1\int_0^{2Y} 6x^2y\,dx\,dy \\
&= 6\int_0^1y\,dy\int_0^{2Y}x^2\,dx
\end{align}
...same as above, but ending up with $\boxed{8y^3}$.

Now this intuitively seems correct as well, since plugging in a value of $0.5$ for $y$ is like asking what is the probability that $X$ is less than $2\cdot 0.5$, or 1, which should also be 1, and it is with $8\cdot(0.5)^3 = 1$

However what I'm confused about slightly now is the range. I assumed that the function range should be redefined as:

$$P\{X < 2Y\} =
\begin{cases}
8y^3,  & 0 \le Y \le 1/2 \\
1, & 1/2 \le Y \le 1  \\
\end{cases}$$

...since obviously the probability cannot be greater than $1$, and the function continues up to $8$ within the original range. Does this all seem correct?

Comment: Your first calculation is incorrect starting from the first expression (failure to distinguish between $Y$ the random variables and a number $y$) and the final answer  $P(X< Y) = 1$ that seems intuitively correct to you is wrong.

Comment: Some of what you wrote can be connected with a way to solve the problem. However, it is in fundamental ways wrong. The cap $Y$ in the integral makes no sense. And the answer to what is the probability that $X\lt Y$ must be a specific **number**, and not an expression in $y$. Maybe it would help to view things more concretely, more geometrically.

Comment: @AndréNicolas But how can the $P\{X < Y\}$ be a number, and not a function, when it depends on the value of y? Maybe I'm fundamentally confused. So $P\{X < Y\}$ is different from $P\{x < y\}$?

Comment: I think I'm misinterpreting it as $P\{x < y |\,y\}$ As in pick a value y, find the probability that x is less than that value.  But $P\{X < Y\}$ is just the probability that x < y when both are chosen randomly?

Comment: Imagine instead that you have $X$ and $Y$ equalling either 1 or 2 with equal probability. IE. $P(X=1)=1/2$, $P(X=2)=1/2$, and the same for $Y$. Now, let's ask $P(X<Y)$. The possible outcomes are $(X,Y) = (1,1), (2,1), (1,2),$ or $(2,2)$. Now the $P(X<Y) = 1/4$ since $(1,2)$ is the only one of the four possibilities that has $X < Y$. But, $1/4$ is a fixed number, not dependent on $Y$.

Comment: Yes. you are fundamentally confused. $\Pr(x\lt y)$ does not even make sense. Now for fixed $y$, $\Pr(X\lt y)$ makes sense, but that is not what you are asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't entirely off track, but instead, you should have $$\int_0^1\int_0^y6x^2y\,dx\,dy.$$ We can certainly pull the $y$ out of the first integrand, but note that our limits of integration *still have a $y$ in them*, so we can't simply turn this into a product of integrals. Instead, evaluating the inner integral first, we have $$\int_0^1y\left(\int_0^y6x^2\,dx\right)\,dy=\int_0^1y(2y^3)\,dy,$$ and I'm sure you can take it from there. The other problem has similar issues and fixes.

The thing to keep in mind, here, is that $Y$ is the name of a function, that can take on values $y$.

Comment: Okay but then the answer would come to 2/5, for any value of y. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Xavier and Yolande each pick a number between $0$ and $1$. The joint density function of the numbers they pick is given to you. You are asked for the probability that Xavier's number is less than Yolande's. There is no $y$ in the game, the answer is a number.

Comment: @CameronBuie Sorry, edited that while you were typing

Comment: @krb686: Given that $Y=y,$ the probability that $X<Y$ will vary. When $Y=0,$ the probability is $0,$ and when $Y=1,$ the probability is $1$. The *average* probability over all possible $y$ is $\frac25,$ which may seem counterintuitive, but keep in mind that the density is *not* uniform.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I really like the "Xavier and Yolande" characterization of random variables! I'll have to keep that in mind for pedagogic reasons.

Answer (score 1):

For the second integral, when you have $P(X<2Y)$, I'd suggest drawing the following region in $\mathbb{R}^2$: First draw the "unit box" with $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1$, that way you know that $(X,Y)$ will land in that box. Now, draw the line corresponding to $x=2y$ (which is, of course, is the line $y=1/2 x$ in the "standard form"). The line will enter the unit box at the origin and exit at the point $(1, 1/2)$. Since the region you are integrating over will be the inside of the box above the line (since this is where $x < 2y$) you need to set up your bounds accordingly. If you integrate $dxdy$ then the integral is
$$
P(X<2Y)=\int_0^{1/2} \int_0^{2y} 6x^2 y\,dxdy + \int_{1/2}^1 \int_0^1 6x^2y \,dxdy
$$
Or, if you want to integrate $dydx$
$$
P(X<2Y)=\int_0^1 \int_{\frac{1}{2}x}^1 6x^2y \,dydx
$$

Comment: thanks makes perfect sense

Comment: Why are you adding rest of half of Y? Don't we just want what's on the line. @Tom